# Calculating total number of values based on same id in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
api_spec_id       commitdates       commits Year-Month API Age info_version  
84                  2014-12-15      110      2014-12     110      6.0.1  
84                  2014-11-06       33      2014-11      33      6.0.2
84                  2014-10-15      110      2014-10     110      6.0.3
84                  2014-12-02      110      2014-12     110      6.0.5
84                  2014-11-19       33      2014-11      33      7.0.2
```

`api_spec_id` is the id for every API in the dataframe, now the same API can have different versions within the same id, as it keeps changing for every commit date.

I want to count that for `api_spec_id` = 84, how many total versions are there, like here there are 5 in total.

My desired output is :

```
api_spec_id       commitdates       commits Year-Month API Age info_version  Total_versions
84                  2014-12-15      110      2014-12     110      6.0.1       5
84                  2014-11-06       33      2014-11      33      6.0.2       5
84                  2014-10-15      110      2014-10     110      6.0.3.      5
84                  2014-12-02      110      2014-12     110      6.0.5.      5
84                  2014-11-19       33      2014-11      33      7.0.2.      5
```

I tried using `value_counts.()`, `sum()` and few other solutions on similar questions found here on stack, however none of the solutions gave me the correct numbers which I want to achieve. What would be the best way to go about this? Any guidance will be really helpful.

Comment: does this help? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: I tried looking at the parameters, but could not get the particular function useful for my use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pd.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `nunique` for this:

```
df['Total_versions'] = df.groupby('api_spec_id').info_version.transform('nunique')
```

It counts the number of unique values in the column `'info_version'` for each `'api_spec_id'`.

Output:

```
api_spec_id commitdates commits Year-Month  API_Age info_version    Total_versions
0   84  2014-12-15  110 2014-12 110 6.0.1   5
1   84  2014-11-06  33  2014-11 33  6.0.2   5
2   84  2014-10-15  110 2014-10 110 6.0.3   5
3   84  2014-12-02  110 2014-12 110 6.0.5   5
4   84  2014-11-19  33  2014-11 33  7.0.2   5
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful, I was able to calculate statistics for some of my other Versioning data as well!